# Adding columns to a dataset in SAS using a for loop

Tags: sas, panel

I'm coming at SAS from a Python/R/Stata background, and learning that things are rather different in SAS. I'm approaching the following problem from the standpoint of one of these languages, perhaps SAS isn't up to what I want to do.

I have a panel dataset with an `age` column in it. I want to add new columns to the dataset using this `age` column. I'm going to simplify the functions of `age` to keep it simple in my example.

The goal is to loop over a sequence, and use the value of that sequence at each loop step to 1. assign the name of the new column and 2. assign the values of that column. I'm hoping to get my starting dataset, with new columns added to it taking values `spline1` `spline2`... `spline7`

```
    data somePath.FinalDataset; 

    do i = 1 to 7;

      if i = 1 then 
        spline&i. = age;

      if i ^= 1 then spline&i. = age + i;

    end; 
    set somePath.StartingDataset;  
    run;
```

This code won't even run, though in an earlier version I was able to get it to run, but the new columns had their values shifted down one row from what they should have been. I include this code block as pseudocode of what I'm trying to do. Any help is much appreciated

Comment: What are you intending to loop over? Is the number of columns (7) fixed or dynamic? I think you need an array.

Comment: You need to post example input and output data so that we can understand what you want to do.  The first obvious issue is that you are trying to manipulate the data before you have read it. Move the SET statement above the other statements so there is some values for AGE for you code to operate on.

Answer (score 4):

One way to do this in SAS is with arrays.  A SAS array can be used to reference a group of variables, and it can also create variables.

```
data have;
  input age;
  cards;
  5
  10
;
run;

data want; 
  set have;
  array spline{7}; *create spline1 spline2 ... spline7;
  do i=1 to 7;
    if i = 1 then spline{i} = age;
    else spline{i} = age + i;
  end;
  drop i;
run;
```

Spline{i} referes to the ith variable of the array named spline.
i is a regular variable, the DROP statement prevents it from being written to the output dataset.

When you say new columns were "shifted by one," note that spline1=age and spline2=age+2.  You can change your code accordingly, e.g. if you want spline2=age+1, you could change your `else` statement to `else spline{i} = age + i - 1 ;`  It is also possible to change the array statement to define it with 0 as the lower bound, rather than 1.

Comment: I would perhaps mention in this answer how SAS arrays are a bit different from arrays in other programming languages (in that they're just defined groups of variables, not a separate variable/object themselves).

Comment: @Joe please feel free to edit to add that info (I don't know enough about other languages to comment intelligently : )

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are likely the best way to solve this, but I will demonstrate a macro approach, which is necessary in some cases.

SAS separates its doing-things-with-data language from its writing-code language into the 'data step language' and the 'macro language'.  They don't really talk to  each other during a data step, because the macro language runs during the compilation stage (before any data is processed) while the data step language runs during the execution stage (while rows of data are being processed).

In any event, for something like this it's quite possible to write a macro to do what you want.  Borrowing Quentin's general structure and initial dataset:

```
data have;
  input age;
  cards;
  5
  10
;
run;

%macro make_spline(var=, count=);
  %local i;
  %do i = 1 %to &count;
    %if &i=1 %then &var.&i. = &var.;
    %else &var.&i. = &var. + &i.;
    ;  *this semicolon ends the assignment statement;
  %end;

  /* You end up with the IF statement generating:
         age1 = age
     and the extra semicolon after the if/else generates the ; for that line, making it
         age1 = age; 
     etc. for the other lines.
  */
%mend make_spline;


data want; 
  set have;
  %make_spline(var=age,count=7);
run;
```

This would then perform what you're looking to perform.  The looping is in the macro language, not in the data step.  You can assign parameters however you see fit; I prefer to have parameters like above, or even more (start loop could also be a parameter, and in fact the assignment code could be a parameter!).